# SANE Support for Canon LiDE 220?

Tags: scanner, sane

I ordered a Canon LiDE 210 scanner because the SANE website says it's "completely" supported.  The vendor delivered a Canon LiDE 220, and it's not recognized.  Is this fixable, or must I return the scanner?

Comment: I wouldn't take the risk and return it 210 is indeed supported

Comment: Same problem here. Could not have it work with Ubuntu 14.04. Tried to play around with the source code to add the 220, but the 210 previous device seems to be too different.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Lide220 without problem. You need to install the latest sane drivers from git. Follow [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompileSaneFromSource) for directions.

Also note that I had to remove USB3 support from my motherboard BIOS to have the Lide220 work flawlessly 100% of the times.

Comment: In fact there's now a sane-git PPA for getting the latest drivers pre-built: https://launchpad.net/~rolfbensch/+archive/ubuntu/sane-git  (currently not quite solving my Lide220 problem, but better than out-of-the-box on 15.04)

Comment: @andybuckley [LiDE 220 is listed as "complete"](http://www.sane-project.org/lists/sane-backends-cvs.html) in SANE docs. What doesn't work?

Comment: It wasn't recognised at all by Ubuntu 15.04 until I installed the sane-git drivers. Now it is recognised but only moves the scan head a little before locking up. A second attempt to scan in Simple Scan crashes the program. Maybe a temporary blip in the current sane-git?

Comment: Yeah. It seems to be working just fine with sane from the PPA.

Comment: I added a note to my original answer. In addition to sane-git I also had to disable USB3 support from my motherboard bios