# SANE vs. Canon LiDE 220

Tags: 14.04, canon, sane

I recently acquired a scanner (Canon Lide 220). Although it is listed as supported by Sane (http://www.sane-project.org/sane-mfgs.html#Z-CANON), I wasn't able to get it working.

I followed the advice posted in [SANE Support for Canon LiDE 220?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/519464/sane-support-for-canon-lide-220) , compiling Sane from sources, to no avail.

`sane-find-scanner` quickly finds the scanner. But `sudo scanimage -L` does not recognize anything.

Then I noticed that the version of the backend (genesys-1.0-63) listed by the sane project is higher than the one just compiled (genesys-1.0.26). Or isn't?

How can I gather/compile the last version?

I realize that there exist a similar question, with answers, but I'm not in a position to suggest an answer, and I do not have enough credits to add my question as a comment.

Just in case it matters, I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1):

There are all kind of complex solutions, like https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompileSaneFromSource but for me they did not work. Using xsane is very easy to use, and did work for me.

Install :

```
sudo apt-get install xsane
```

Then call :

```
sudo sane-find-scanner
```

Your scanner should be displayed in the result.

Then call :

```
scanimage -L
```

If this results positive your scanner is recognized.

Comment: Thank you for this post! I was able to easily add my Canon LiDE 220 scanner to Ubuntu 20.04 and use it within Gimp.

Comment: @Kevin I am happy it did work for you. Could show this, to mark my answer as useful?